# JAXB repeated parsing of small xml documents

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some huge log files where each line is a complete xml document.  I need to read each line, parse the xml, and perform some operations on each document.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mylogfile.xml");
String line = rdr.readLine();
int numLines = 1;
while (line != null) {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    // do something with the parsed xml
    line = rdr.readLine();
}
```

This reads and processes at about 28K lines per second.  Not bad, but I think it can be better.  I am only interested in some particular tags, but do need to know if the xml contains other nested tags or if it is invalid xml.  I tried a regex parser, but the documents may contain some CDATA that it was not worth re-implementing an xml parser.

What performance gains could I expect from using the method?  If it's only 50% increase, then it may not be worth the effort, but 2 or 3 fold is certainly worth it.

I prefer using standard Java libraries.

Comment: If you need more speed i don't recommend you an xml parser. You could try [XPATH](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) at least to rule out the lines in error.

Comment: Can you provide a representative data set which includes all the challenging elements?

Comment: The xml data is proprietary, but each line, including the xml start is usually under 1K bytes.  Each line/document contains about 7 nodes, but some documents may contain some other nested nodes or CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only interested in particular tags, I would recommend using a [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) parser.
It seems to do everything you need.

Will be probably more performant than your current approach since it won't create a DOM tree in memory (which you seem to be doing an the moment). At the same time, StAX is much easier API than SAX (pull vs. push parsing).

Although I'm a big fan of JAXB, I won't recommend it for your task. You're only interested in certain and probably very limited set of tags, you don't really need to map your XML onto Java structures. JAXB can work with StAX too, but it will add certain reflection overhead. And you'll also need to filter down to elements you're interested in, which is not quite easy when combining StAX and JAXB. (Otherwise you'll unmarshall the whole XML which is overhead).

Also take a look at [Digester](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/) however I'm not quite sure about performance.

Comment: I have used StAX cursor API, and it was slightly faster.  Just about 35k lines/sec in best cases.

Comment: @Ayman Also check VTD-XML. But I don't think you can do much better unless you do some really black magic like finite automata. Also try different StAX parsers (ex. Woodstox).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to increase performance by 2x (56k+ lines/sec) by using `java.util.regex`.  Yes this does contradict my initial post of needing the nesting and CDATA handling, but it does work if the nesting is not an issue if handling any tags is known by name.

The regex I used is the two group matcher:

```
    Pattern tag = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>(([^<]|<!\\[CDATA\\[.*?]]>)+)</\\1>");
    Matcher matcher = tag.matcher(""); // we will reset this at each line
```

The `matcher` is reset for each line instead of new instance created, and that does save on memory and with less GC, there is a noticeable performance increase.

Would probably also get increase in performance by using JFlex or another lexer generator to extract the tags needed as tokens.  But that is another exercise.